# Video play pause triggering with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a full background video and a footer(120px height) over it.

I'm trying to figure out to do the following;

The footer has to get smaller (about 100px) once the video starts to play. But the code doesn't seems to work.

```
   if (!$('#video')[0].play) { 
     $('#video').css({"height":100px"});
    }
```

Also, just like a YouTube player, on mouse position change over the video I want to change the footer size(120px again).

Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the mouseenter and ended events to increase the height of the footer and mouseleave and playing events to reduce the height

```
$('#video').on('mouseenter ended', function () {
    $('#footer').height(120);
}).on('mouseleave playing', function () {
    $('#footer').height(100);
})
```

Comment: @ErimFranci did you change the `$('#footer')` selector to match your footer element

Comment: @ErimFranci you need to share your html of the corresponding elements